# average based on column condition in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find the average number for a specific number of columns that will be changable. For example, in the below I want to find a way where I can get the average for each month for a select number of columns (here Alice and John). This however may change so I'm trying to make it as easy to change as possible (so make it Bob, John & Jo for example)

[image]

I can do SUMPRODUCT for one but it doesn't seem to allow me to have multiple column names in there. In an ideal world, I could have something whereby I could change "Alice, John" to any combination that will work. I can think of how to do this in R but not excel; maybe because it's a Friday afternoon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on your version of excel you can use averageifs: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690

Answer (score 1):

If one has **Office 365**:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(B2:E2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&SUBSTITUTE($B$1:$E$1," ","")&",",","&SUBSTITUTE($F$1," ","")&","))))
```

[image]

If not:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&SUBSTITUTE($B$1:$E$1," ","")&",",","&SUBSTITUTE($F$1," ","")&",")),B2:E2))
```

If not using `Office 365 Excel`, this will need to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> when exiting `edit mode`.

[image]

Or:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B2:E2,$B$1:$E$1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($F$1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))/COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($F$1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]